# Presure vs Energy density

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

I'm having trouble to intepretate a graph where in the y-axis there is Pressure ( $P \equiv=-\frac{\partial E}{\partial V}$) and on the x-axis energy density ( $\varepsilon\equiv$ E/V ). If there is a inflexion point and it is a monotonically growing function, what does this means thermodinamically?
Here the graphic:
[image: EoS-HybridStar]

This is the pressure vs energy density profile of a neutror hybrid star, tha black curve is the pure hadron matter the green one is the pure quark matter, and in the middle the pasta phase that occurs on the mixed phase, where a first order phase transition is being developed. (Gibb's Construction). The purple are the droplets (quarks inside a sphere, surrounded by a sea of hadrons), then orange are the rods (quarks inside a cylinder), cyan the slabs, magenta thetubes (hadrons inside a cylinder inmersed on a sea of quarks), and finally bubbles of blue color (sphere wth hadrons inside)

Comment: couldn't load an image to show you the funcion graph

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pressure-as-a-function-of-density-at-temperatures-th-085-10-and-115-At-th-085_fig1_256744561
is this useful?

Comment: not really, or at leat couldn't find anything that helps @MpH81679

Comment: Can you give the source?

Comment: there, the problem was i was trying to upload a pdf @Chemomechanics

Comment: For clarity and readability, please consider translating the legend and giving the context.